# if with start elements broken in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Doing something simple:

```
<table>
    <body>
      @foreach (PlayerBanModel ban in Model.Bans)
      {
         if (ban.Active)
         {
           <tr style="background: yellow">
         }
         else
         {
            <tr style="background: lightgrey">
         }


       <td>@ban.Active </td>
       </tr>
       }
  </table>
```

I left out all the other fields, and the header row.

Error is thrown because it is "The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character. "

Which, of course, it isn't, but it sees Two tr's - one in each conditional, and doesn't realize (apparently) that only one of those will ever be rendered and it expects me to close the  before the }

I tried adding:

```
             if (false)
             {
             </tr>
             }
```

But it apparently is smart enough to remove that.

And I tried to put it in a conditional:

```
<tr style="background: @{return (ban.Active?"white":"lightgrey"}>
```

And various similar attempts.
I might be able to put it in its own partial, but I expect that won't work either.

Suggestions?

I'm using MVC5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditional formatting is incorrect. When using an explicit code nugget you just need to wrap the conditional statement in brackets, not braces, without a return statement.

```
<tr style="background: @(ban.Active ? "white" : "lightgrey")">
```

As for your original code, the parser is interpreting some of the markup as code since it's within the `if` statement. You can mark the lines as specifically being text using `@:`, but it's easier to just do the inline conditional.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (PlayerBanModel ban in Model.Bans) {
      if (ban.Active) {
        @:<tr style="background: yellow">
      }
      else {
        @:<tr style="background: lightgrey">
      }
      <td>@ban.Active </td>
      @:</tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah, I had that, but Resharper gave me " unexpected character sequence in property value" after the @, and "The closing brace doesn't match an opening brace." right after the (  - I guess I forgot to try that combination in the actual rendered page.   There I go trusting Resharper again :-(  Thanks!

Comment: This is a great work around (the way I originally wanted to do it), but still doesn't address the original problem - which does seem to be a MVC5 bug.  - Granted, making it work could make the compiler more complex, but it should work.